# Error in plugin 'run-sequence(run-internal)'

Tags: linux, azure, gulp, raspberry-pi, run-sequence

I'm performing Iot project using Azure platform. And while I'm doing with manual in Microsoft azure site to make Iot hub communicate with raspberry-pi, I got some error but I cannot find the reasons.

(Manual link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-c-lesson4-send-cloud-to-device-messages 
and I got error when I execute command line "gulp deploy && gulp run")

I think those are error in gulp but I cannot solve that problem and I cannot find any information about the error code, "'run-internal' errored" and "Error in plugin 'run-sequence(run-internal)'".

OS: Windows 10
Tool: Visual studio 2015, Azure

Here is the image of terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsmB2.png)

Comment: Do you ensure your IP correctly? You could try to `ssh FCZ.azure-devices.net`. According to the error log, it seems `ssh` failed.

Comment: As your recommend, I tried the command line ssh FCZ.azure-devices.net but I cannot execute the command "ssh" because my os is Windows 10. Thank you. I'm finding what is the "ssh" in windows 10.

Comment: Hi, I check the article you provided, do you `enable ssh`? Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-c-lesson1-configure-your-device#enable-ssh).

Comment: I checked about that and it is enable ssh. And we also did lesson 1(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-c-lesson1-deploy-blink-app) few days ago and there was no problem. Thank you :)

Comment: According to the log, you had better check why `ssh` fail.

Comment: Okay Thank you for you advice :)

Comment: Hi, you had better add a tag `Linux` on your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error log, it seems the script could not ssh to your server.

You should check why you could not `ssh` to your server firstly and try again.

Comment: I searched for that and I think protocol MQTT is a problem.
In manual, they use AMQP but we use MQTT and I heard that MQTT can be a problem because they use port 8883